# double free or corruption (!prev) while calling __do_global_dtors_aux

Tags: c++, gcc, memory-management, g++

I'm getting this error message after my app has done everything right

```
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3f1ee70d7f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4b)[0x3f1ee711db]
/home/user/workspace/NewProject/build/bin/TestApp(_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIN5boost10shared_ptrINS1_5uuids4uuidEEEE10deallocateEPS5_m+0x20)[0x49c174]
/home/user/workspace/NewProject/build/bin/TestApp(_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIN5boost10shared_ptrINS0_5uuids4uuidEEESaIS4_EE13_M_deallocateEPS4_m+0x32)[0x495b84]
/home/user/workspace/NewProject/build/bin/TestApp(_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIN5boost10shared_ptrINS0_5uuids4uuidEEESaIS4_EED2Ev+0x47)[0x49598b]
/home/user/workspace/NewProject/build/bin/TestApp(_ZNSt6vectorIN5boost10shared_ptrINS0_5uuids4uuidEEESaIS4_EED1Ev+0x65)[0x48bf27]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__cxa_finalize+0x8e)[0x3f1ee337fe]
/home/user/workspace/NewProject/build/components/lib_path/libhelper-d.so[0x2aaaab052b36]
```

If I run the program in `gdb` I can get the following backtrace, but it is all I get:

```
#0  0x0000003f1ee30285 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003f1ee31d30 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000003f1ee692bb in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x0000003f1ee70d7f in _int_free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000003f1ee711db in free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x000000000049c174 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<boost::shared_ptr<boost::uuids::uuid> >::deallocate (this=0x2aaaab2cea50, __p=0x1cfd8d0)
    at /opt/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/ext/new_allocator.h:95
#6  0x0000000000495b84 in std::_Vector_base<boost::shared_ptr<boost::uuids::uuid>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<boost::uuids::uuid> > >::_M_deallocate (
    this=0x2aaaab2cea50, __p=0x1cfd8d0, __n=8) at /opt/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/bits/stl_vector.h:146
#7  0x000000000049598b in std::_Vector_base<boost::shared_ptr<boost::uuids::uuid>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<boost::uuids::uuid> > >::~_Vector_base (
    this=0x2aaaab2cea50, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
    at /opt/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/bits/stl_vector.h:132
#8  0x000000000048bf27 in std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::uuids::uuid>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<boost::uuids::uuid> > >::~vector (this=0x2aaaab2cea50,
    __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /opt/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/bits/stl_vector.h:313
#9  0x0000003f1ee337fe in __cxa_finalize () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#10 0x00002aaaab052b36 in __do_global_dtors_aux ()
from /home/user/workspace/NewProject/build/components/lib_path/libhelper-d.so
#11 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I really have no idea of how to proceed from here.

**UPDATE** I forgot to mention that the only global variable of the type which appears in the error is cleared `m_uuids.size() == 0` by the time the error appear.

Comment: This is exactly why they made programs like valgrind.

Comment: You're mistaken about your app doing "everything right". Your app has undefined behaviour because you coded it wrong, and you're now seeing the fallout of that error.

Comment: I really have no idea of how we can find a bug if we don't see the code.

Comment: Is difficult to understand without seeing the code, but this seems a problem related to some delete or free. Are you sure that the memory allocated with `new` is always freed with `delete` and the memory allocated with `malloc` is freed with `free`?

Comment: you're also probably freeing a already freed memory...or deleting an already deleted area

Comment: 1. Well, I didn't write the code, but I became the mantainer. All code uses shared_ptr's which make the problems even more strange. And I cannot show the code, because I haven't even found the vector with the problems

Comment: Compiling with `-ggdb` and using `gdb`'s ability to list code might help. (If it really is a double-free, check whether you aren't freeing some memory in a class that a destructor handles on its own.)

Answer (score 7):

I had this same problem using glog.  In my case, it was this scenario:

1. I had a share library, call it 'common.so' that linked glog.
2. My main executable, call it 'app' also linked glog, and linked in common.so.

The problem I had was that glog was linked statically in both the .so and the exectuable.  When I changed both #1 and #2 to link the .so instead of the .a, the problem went away.

Not sure this is your problem, but it could be.  Generally speaking, corruption when freeing up memory often means that you corrupted the memory pool (such as deleting the same pointer twice).  I believe linking in the .a in both cases, I was getting cleanup behavior on the same global pointer (an std::string in my case) twice.

Update:
After much investigation, this is very likely the problem.  What happens is that each the executable and the .so have a global variable of std::string type (part of glog).  These std::string global variables must be constructed when the object (exe, .so) is loaded by the dynamic linker/loader.  Also, a destructor for each is added for cleanup using **at_exit**.  However, when it comes time for **at_exit** functions to be called, both global reference point to the same std::string.  That means the std::string destructor is called twice, but on the same object.  Then **free** is called on the same memory location twice.  Global std::string (or any class with a constructor) are a bad idea.  If you choose to have a .so based architecture (a good idea), you have to be careful with all 3rd party libraries and how they handle globals.  You stay out of most danger by linking to the .so for all 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Where the error is appearing is probably a little misleading. My best guess would be that you've got a vector of shared pointers and as it's being destroyed, one (at least) of those shared pointers is trying to delete the object that it's pointing to, only to find that it has already been deleted.

Are you mixing raw pointers with shared pointers anywhere? If so, you might find a perfectly innocuous looking `delete` somewhere which is pulling the rug from under the feet of your `shared_ptr`